# using request promise in lambda handler will abandon call

Tags: lambda, request, bots, gateway

I have found quite a few comments around this topic, but none that actually work for me. I am building a facebook bot. Say for now I only want to echo the text back to the caller. I have a working example of this using ec2. When moving to lambda, it does not work. Here is my code:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
...
} else if (event.httpMethod == 'POST') {
    var data = JSON.parse(event.body);
    if (data.object == 'page') {
        data.entry.forEach(function(pageEntry) {
            // Iterate over each messaging event
            pageEntry.messaging.forEach(function(messagingEvent) {
                if (messagingEvent.message) {
                    receivedMessage(messagingEvent);
                }
            });
        });
    }
    //if I only use callback like the documentation states, gateway always says 502, regardless of the message content in second param, or even using no params
    //callback(null, JSON.stringify({"statusCode": 200, "headers": {"content-type":"application.json"}, "body": ""}));
    //if i answer using succeed, gateway says 200 ok, bot never gets post
    context.succeed({"statusCode": 200, "headers": {"content-type":"application.json"}, "body": ""});
}

function receivedMessage(event) {
var senderID = event.sender.id;
var messageText = message.text;
if (messageText) {
    var messageData = {
        recipient: {
          id: senderID
        },
        message: {
          text: messageText,
          metadata: "DEVELOPER_DEFINED_METADATA"
        }
      };
    callSendAPI(messageData);
}
```

}

```
function callSendAPI(messageData) {
request({
    uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me/messages',
    qs: { access_token: PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN },
    method: 'POST',
    json: messageData
}).then(function(body) {
    console.log('success');
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.error("Failed calling Send API", err);
});
```

}

I tried moving the context.succeed in the .then part but gateway gets 502. If I hit the 'test' button in the aws lambda console, messenger gets the message. It seems that the promise exists with the call but it is not triggered.

I read many posts on the subject and tried many of the answers, with no success. I read others had same issue using claudiajs, with or without claudia promises.

For now I am considering moving back to ec2. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This documentation states that context must be set in the case of a API Gateway lambda proxy: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format

The problem I was having is that upon error on catch, I was not calling context.fail, which ended in a 502 bad gateway and calls would not be received after. All paths must have context set.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between using `callback(...)` and `context.succeed(...)`, is the `context.succeed(...)` call will make Lambda wait for an empty event loop. See this link for more details: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html

In your code example when you call `callback(...)`, there are still events from receivedMessage and callSendAPI in the event loop. The code doesn't chain the resulting promises and 'wait' for those to complete before calling `callback(...)`. You could also build up a response and call a callback in each of the two methods.

I'd recommend returning promises from receivedMessage & callSendAPI, and calling the callback after all of the messages have been processed.

Something like this might work:

```js
/* This goes inside your handler */
//using Bluebird promises
Promise.all(Promise.map(data.entry, pageEntry => {
    // Iterate over each messaging event
    return Promise.all(
             pageEntry.messaging
                  .filter(e => e.message)
                  .map(messagingEvent => 
                     receivedMessage(messagingEvent)));
 })).then(res => callback(null, res))
   .catch(err => callback(err));
/* The code above goes in your handler */

function receivedMessage(event) {
    var senderID = event.sender.id;
    var messageText = message.text;
    if (messageText) {
       var messageData = {
                recipient: {
                  id: senderID
                },
                message: {
                    text: messageText,
                    metadata: "DEVELOPER_DEFINED_METADATA"
                }
              };
       return callSendAPI(messageData);
    } else {
       return Promise.resolve({});
    }
}

function callSendAPI(messageData) {
         return request({
               uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me/messages',
               qs: { access_token: PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN },
               method: 'POST',
               json: messageData
          });
}
```

Comment: This documentation states that context must be set: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format

Comment: The `context.succeed(...)` result must be in the specified JSON format for integrations with API Gateway. For the example code I provided, that would probably be `context.succeed(JSON.stringify({statusCode: 200, body: res})) ` rather than `callback(null, res)`.

Comment: If you are only using Lambda, you can still use the callback solution with the result as it is in your original code.